# Strange subplot effect with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to plot my data as follows:

First subplot

```
alpha = ['Joy', 'fear', 'sadness', 'thankful','anger','surprise','love']
fig = pl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(511,title='SGD')
cax = ax.matshow(cm)
fig.colorbar(cax)

ax.set_xticklabels(['']+alpha)
ax.set_yticklabels(['']+alpha)
```

Second subplot later on with new cm:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(521,title='LIBLINEAR')
cax = ax.matshow(cm)
fig.colorbar(cax)

ax.set_xticklabels(['']+alpha)
ax.set_yticklabels(['']+alpha)
```

Third subplot later on with new cm:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(512,title='MNB')
cax = ax.matshow(cm)
fig.colorbar(cax)

ax.set_xticklabels(['']+alpha)
ax.set_yticklabels(['']+alpha)
```

Fourth subplot later on with new cm

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(522,title='BNB')
cax = ax.matshow(cm)
fig.colorbar(cax)

ax.set_xticklabels(['']+alpha)
ax.set_yticklabels(['']+alpha)
```

Last subplot with new cm

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(532,title='NC')
cax = ax.matshow(cm)
fig.colorbar(cax)

ax.set_xticklabels(['']+alpha)
ax.set_yticklabels(['']+alpha)
pl.show()
```

I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You change the layout of the subplots every time. You use `fig.add_subplot(511)` which is short for `fig.add_subplot(n_rows, n_columns, index)`. `n_rows` and `n_columns` determine the layout of the sub plots in the figure, `index` the position (starting with 1).

So if you want to have five rows and two columns, you make

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(5,2,1)
(...)
ax = fig.add_subplot(5,2,2)
(...)    
ax = fig.add_subplot(5,2,3)
```

to plot 1st row, 1st column; 1st row, 2nd column; 2nd row, 1st column etc.

Again, note that `fig.add_subplot(5,2,1)` and `fig.add_subplot(521)` are equivalent.

Comment: +1: It would also be useful to show the right way to do what the OP is trying to accomplish.